# A word for happy music with sad lyrics

Tags: single-word-requests

is there a word to identify a song where the music is happy but the lyrics are sad?

What about the opposite a song where the music is sad but the lyrics are happy?

Thanks

Comment: not  the answer but something to let you start your own research, when something is both pleasant and sad   : bitter-sweet  "pleasant but tinged with sadness"  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bittersweet

Comment: It's called lyrical dissonance.

Comment: Jenn, your answer may be good. To be judged, though, it needs verification from reliable sources. You should cite sources that will confirm your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Further to @J.Taylor's advice, note that the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to avoid deletion - for example, adding a published example or definition for *lyrical dissonance*, linked to the source. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: A new and relevant answer to an old question is always delightful to see. To show that yours is the right answer, it's best to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. For example, you could offer evidence, such as the definition from a good online dictionary, or examples of it in the wild. You could contrast your answer with other answers. This is what makes answers most useful – to the asker, and to future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

To a large extent, it depends on what you mean by *happy* and *sad*.

Both **grunge** music and **punk** (e.g. Pearl Jam and the Clash, respectively) have rhythms that are energetic, peppy, and excellent to dance to; however, the content of the lyrics tend to deal with death, love lost, promises broken, and of course (the cover of) "I Fought the Law [and the Law Won]." And what about nursery rhymes like "Humpty Dumpty"?

I'd say **gospel** and **opera** have the general ability to portray happy themes with sad melodies, "Amazing Grace," for instance. I would call these types of songs **uplifting**.

Music is generally categorized by genre. But certain bands take on an energy of their own, capable of performing both types of music you mention without ready categorization, such as the Grateful Dead and Depeche Mode (or when I was in high school, Depressed Mood).

*I don't like giving answers with social references, but it is a question about music.*

Comment: Since you mentioned Depeche Mode (a band that I love) the song Strange Love is a perfect example of it. It has very happy music but the lyrics a sad.

Answer (score 0):

Discordant is good but Bittersweet is more apt. Depends on perspective too. Lyrics can belie the positive melody and the opposite also occurs where 'up' lyrics are sung to a sad melody.

Answer (score -2):

The term ***prosody*** could be helpful to describe what you are looking for.

To the degree that the sad or happy feel of the music is due to the meter, pronunciation, and emphasis of how the words are sung, you could say the music lacks good ***prosody***. ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/152998?redirectedFrom=prosody#eid) but use Wikipedia link below if you do not have an OED account)

**EDIT ADDRESSING FIRST 2 COMMENTS:**  ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_(linguistics)))

> In linguistics, prosody (from Ancient Greek: προσῳδίᾱ prosōidíā "song sung to music; tone or accent of a syllable", Attic Greek pronunciation: [prosɔː(i)díaː]) is concerned with those elements of speech that are not individual phonetic segments (vowels and consonants) but are properties of syllables and larger units of speech. These contribute to linguistic functions such as intonation, tone, stress, and rhythm. **Prosody may reflect various features of the speaker or the utterance: the emotional state of the speaker**; the form of the utterance (statement, question, or command); the presence of irony or sarcasm; emphasis, contrast, and focus; or other elements of language that may not be encoded by grammar or by choice of vocabulary.

Also, you might consider describing the music as being ***discordant*** or even ***dissonant*** with the lyrics.  Although used generally to refer to the clash of any two elements (e.g. "[dissonance](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=definition%20of%20dissonance&spf=1497457017880) between campaign rhetoric and personal behavior"), [discord](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/53940?rskey=TWPL9P&result=1#eid) and dissonance in the first instance are used to refer to musical *notes* that are not in harmony.  So, this might cause confusion since you are in the context of music -- people may assume you are talking about dissonant musical *notes* rather than dissonance between the feel of the tune and the lyrics.

Comment: Prosody has nothing directly to do with the emotional content / effect of a piece of music.

Comment: Could you provide a link that doesn't require an OED account?

Comment: I humbly disagree with @Edwin Ashworth - According to Wikipedia, prosody "may reflect...the emotional state of the speaker."

Comment: _Prosody_ can't be said to be a word meaning 'a song where the music is happy but the lyrics are sad'. Facial expressions usually reflect the emotional state of a speaker. But that doesn't mean 'a song where the music is happy but the lyrics are sad' can be called a facial expression.

Comment: There are also songs that are intentionally humorous by contrasting sad lyrics with happy music. For example, in "The Train," a semi-serious song, the Roches sang, "He's miserable, I'm miserable, we are miserable" in cheerful, chirpy voices. There are other songs like this, but I don't know of a name for that kind of song.